# Why does my published solution only install an application reference and not the full application on a separate computer?

Tags: c#, installation

I developed an application in Visual Studio 2019 c# that uses a database. The connection string I use is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\C-Sharp\PasswordSecrets\PasswordSecrets.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

In my app.config file I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="pws" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PasswordSecrets.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However, I did not set the `DataDirectory` variable. The programs works perfectly when I run it in Visual Studio. But when I publish it into an installer, I get no errors, and I copy it onto a flash drive to install it onto a computer that is not attached to a network.

It installs with no errors and when I try to run it, nothing happens. I found it installed as an application reference pointing to the start menu. When I try to run it from the start menu I get the same results. Nothing.

So what is wrong? What else do I have to setup to get it to install and run properly?

Comment: Did the installer place any files on the computer where it ran?  What happens if you double-click the .exe file directly?  Also check Windows Event Viewer for .NET exceptions during application load that prevented showing your main window.

Comment: The only file placed on the computer was an application reference file. No .exe file was installed on the computer. When I double-clicked on the application reference, nothing happened

Comment: Something went wrong when you created your installer project then.  Perhaps you selected "Application Reference" when you were looking for "The output binary of another project" like a project reference?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that. Where would "Application Reference" be set?

Comment: It would be highly specific to what tool you used for "publish it into an installer".  I don't know if you're using the same type of installer project as I have in the past.  There are probably thousands of competing plugins for Visual Studio for building installers.  Some of special note are WiX, being one of the more widely used, and a crippled edition of InstallShield which was bundled with some editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WiXToolset

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even know there were plugins for Visual Studio. In fact, I didn't even install an installer plugin to Visual Studio. I was just using the setup publisher that came with it.

Comment: Even "the setup publisher that came with it" and knowing you have VS 2019 doesn't uniquely identify it... there are a few different options available during VS setup, depending on the edition (Community vs Professional vs Enterprise)

Comment: I am using VS 2019 Community. Would this allow me to build a setup.exe file that would install all the necessary files? if so, what are the settings I need? Also, I do Have the Wix installer, so if you're more familiar with that how would I work with that?